# eLearning Module

Tags: plugins

Is there a good eLearning module?

ie. Create classes, quizzes, grades, etc.

I'm just scanning for general information right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://buddypress.org/community/groups/buddypress-courseware/
A plugin for buddypress Here’s the features list:

**class**

- Dashboard
- Courses
- Works for both learning models:
  European/United States
- Bibliography
- BibTex Import
- Assignments
- Responses

**Forum integration**

**Gradebook**

**CSV Import**

- Schedules Calendar Month,Week, Day
  view
- iCal export

  Customization using an external CSS
  And more.